# Oracle command WHERE with IF

Tags: database, oracle

With help from here I got my data looks like this:

[image]

`Pumpe1_1` is my data, `Next_` is the value of the following row, `Priv_` the value of the row behind.

Now I'm trying to select only the green marked rows, the condition is that I only need data when `Pumpe1_1` changes from `True` to `False` or the other direction. There I stuck and need help.

Tried so far:

```
SELECT Pumpe1_1, next_, priv_
FROM pump_box_hist
where ((Pumpe1_1 = 'TRUE' and next_ != 'TRUE') or (Pumpe1_1 = 'False' and next_ != 'True')) AND (priv_ != next_ OR next_ != priv_);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show data as formatted text, not as images; not everyone can access the image site, for a start. What is the problem with with you have tried? Aside from the case in your conditions not matching your data values (as a string, "TRUE" is not the same as "True").

Comment: Why is the second row green when it hasn't changed from the first row?

Comment: @ jpw Sry didn't explain good enough, I always need the first/last row of the changes, so the second row is the last with `FALSE` and the next is `TRUE`. It's also because there is the first switch from `FALSE` to `TRUE` (database starts with `FALSE`)

Comment: @LalitKumarB I already got this tip and the `next_` and `priv_` columns are already created with `LAG / LEAD`. I think this must something be with the priority of the `AND` and `OR`

Comment: @katz: `I always need the first/last row of the changes`. Well, why didn't you highlight those records then?

Comment: @RagingBull sry I'm a little bit confused, the highlighted rows are correct, only at the beginning I need the last row (database starts with `FALSE`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the selecting the first row of the changes, you can do :

```
SELECT Pumpe1_1, next_, priv_
FROM pump_box_hist
WHERE (Pumpe1_1 = next_ AND Pumpe1_1 <> priv_)
```

Result:

```
Pumpe1_1    NEXT_   PREV_
-------------------------------
TRUE        TRUE    FALSE
FALSE       FALSE   TRUE
TRUE        TRUE    FALSE
FALSE       FALSE   TRUE
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e5cd/2).

**NB:** I don't think there is any logic behind selecting the first record in the highlighted list.

If so, you have to append it to the result using `union`:

```
SELECT 'FALSE' as Pumpe1_1, 'TRUE' as next_, 'FALSE' as priv_

UNION ALL

SELECT Pumpe1_1, next_, priv_
FROM pump_box_hist
WHERE (Pumpe1_1 = next_ AND Pumpe1_1 <> priv_)
```